# Is there a master list somewhere of the tags and their meanings for mhtml files?

Tags: python, excel, lxml, mhtml

I am trying to read and extract data from xls files that are really Single File Web Pages see below

```
This document is a Single File Web Page, also known as a Web Archive file.
```

I am trying to figure out the meaning of all of the tags so I can make sure I parse them correctly using lxml.

For example here is an example of a tag:

```
 <th class=3Dtl colspan=3D1 rowspan=3D2
```

While I am having success working with the few files I am toying with I want to try to figure out if I am making assumptions that will later come back to haunt me.  Thus, a list of these tags and their meaning would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If the MHTML is generated from Microsoft Word, it's probably a combination of [WordprocessingML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212812.aspx) and [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html) tags.

> The top-level elements in a WordprocessingML document are:

```
SmartTagType element describes a Smart Tag type used in the document.
DocumentProperties element contains Office Document Properties.
CustomDocumentProperties element contains Custom Office Document Properties.
schemaLibrary element defines a collection of schemas that comprise a document's schema library.
fonts element (wordDocumentElt complexType) contains font information
frameset element (wordDocumentElt complexType) contains HTML Frameset definitions.
styles element (wordDocumentElt complexType) contains style definitions.
divs element contains HTML DIV information.
shapeDefaults element contains drawing defaults.
docOleData element contains supplemental data containing storages for OLE objects.
docSuppData element contains supplemental data containing toolbar customizations, envelope data, and the Microsoft Visual Basic project.
docPr element contains document options.
shapeDefaults element contains the wrapper representing the shape defaults.
bgPict element contains background picture information.
body element contains the document body.
```

> However, the simplest WordprocessingML document consists of just five elements (and a single namespace). The five elements are:

```
wordDocument element: The root element for a WordprocessingML document.
body element: The container for the displayable text.
p element: A paragraph.
r element: A contiguous set of WordprocessingML components with a consistent set of properties.
t element: A piece of text.
```